# UIScrollView displaying Camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

I have created a camera view to be displayed on the screen by creating a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and now I would like it to be able to be displayed inside of my scroll view.  Currently my scroll view is set up to handle UIImageViews but not the camera layer.  Here is how it all works together:

//Set Up the Camera View
    [self setCaptureManager:[[CaptureManager alloc] init]];

```
[[self captureManager] addVideoInput];

[[self captureManager] addVideoPreviewLayer];
CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
[[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setBounds:layerRect];
[[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                                              CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[[self captureManager] previewLayer]];

[[captureManager captureSession] startRunning];


int PageCount = 2;
NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:settingsView,captureManager,nil];
UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[scroller setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
scroller.bounces = NO;
scroller.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scroller];
int width=scroller.frame.size.width;
int xPos=0;
for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
{
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
    UIView *view2 = [arrImageName objectAtIndex:i];
    [view1 addSubview:view2];
    [scroller addSubview:view1];
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
    width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
    xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
}
```

The capture manager handles the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` and this all works fine and displays by itself.  I am trying to get it to show up inside my `scrollView` so I have commented out the `CGRect` `layerRect` and instead am trying to get it displayed in my array on the `scrollView`.  At the bottom of the `scrollView`, I have a `UIImageView` that is taking the array and displaying it, however this wont obviously work as the camera is not an Image.  What can I change or look into at the bottom to make this work?  Change it to a `UIView`?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After your loop, just create and add `UIView` at the bottom of the your `UIScrollView` (with proper position and rect). Then, add video preview layer as a sublayer to the view added to the scrollView. Good Luck!

**EDIT**
ok, try this:

```
[[self captureManager] addVideoInput];

[[self captureManager] addVideoPreviewLayer];
CGRect layerRect = [[[self view] layer] bounds];
[[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setBounds:layerRect];
[[[self captureManager] previewLayer] setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                                              CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];
UIView *captureView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[[captureView layer] addSublayer:[[self captureManager] previewLayer]];

[[captureManager captureSession] startRunning];


int PageCount = 2;
NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:settingsView,captureView,nil];
UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[scroller setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
scroller.bounces = NO;
scroller.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:scroller];
int width=scroller.frame.size.width;
int xPos=0;
for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
{
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
    UIView *view2 = [arrImageName objectAtIndex:i];
    [view1 addSubview:view2];
    [scroller addSubview:view1];
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
    width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
    xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks so I edited the code and changed it to a UIView and im close but I am getting the error `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CaptureManager superview]:` Any Ideas?

Comment: That solved the superview issue and it is working without error however now it is not displaying anything but the white screen from my viewController.  I think its close though!